# Download image via javascript and insert into multiple img elements

Tags: javascript, html, image, download

Is it possible to download an image via javascript and insert it into multiple IMG elements? So I have a card layout with detailed information. And in front of each information, there is a little icon to support the details. And it's a bad way when every icon downloads new. So I need to download the image one time and insert the downloaded image into a few IMG elements.

Comment: Yes, it's possible

Comment: Post your code. Read [mcve]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update:** While the solution below will work, the browser does cache images so it the solution is not necessary.

Yes this is possible: https://staxmanade.com/2017/02/how-to-download-and-convert-an-image-to-base64-data-url/

You would use `fetch` to retrieve the image. Once you've gotten the response you can convert it to a blob which can then be converted to a Base64 encoded string and set as the src of your `<img/>` elements.

See the code below (from the linked article):

```
async function getBase64ImageFromUrl(imageUrl) {
  var res = await fetch(imageUrl);
  var blob = await res.blob();

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    var reader  = new FileReader();
    reader.addEventListener("load", function () {
      resolve(reader.result);
    }, false);

    reader.onerror = () => {
      return reject(this);
    };
    reader.readAsDataURL(blob);
  })
}
```

You could then use this function like this to set the *src* attribute:

```
getBase64ImageFromUrl('http://approvaltests.com/images/logo.png')
    .then(result => testImage.src = result)
    .catch(err => console.error(err));
```

Comment: No need. The browser will cache by himself after the first request.

Comment: @aloisdgmovingtocodidact.com So I can use the same image_urls for the src of multiple img elements and the browser will automatically download the image only one time and insert it in all img elements with the same src?

Comment: That is correct. Although like the comment above says: the browser will cache the image after the first request so it should still only make one request.  You can create a page with multiple `<img/>` elements all linking to the same image and look in the *Network* tab of your developer tools and you should see it only downloads the image once.

Comment: @MarcusDerem Yes. If this was your trouble, be relieved the browser will help you here.

Comment: @aloisdgmovingtocodidact.com The last question. Is this working in all browsers?

Comment: @MarcusDerem Follow Ivan Kahl's advice. Try it yourself and learn :)